# Android RecylerView Error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a problem in android `RecylerView` .

`RecylerView` Error:

```
 "The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, 
                          Create Class)" after adding in xml file.
```

Though I have added `appcompat supportv7`.

plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will also need to add the following to your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
```

Taken info from [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/features.html)

Update For Eclipse:

if eclipse is the case then add `android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar` in the libs folder of your project, it will be present inside `sdk\extras\android\support\v7\recyclerview\libs`

Comment: I am having problem in eclipse.

Comment: if eclipse is the case then add "android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar" in the libs folder of your project, it will be present inside "sdk\extras\android\support\v7\recyclerview\libs "

Comment: sir  thanx.It worked.

Comment: Great dont forget to mark it as correct so it clears the "Unanswered" queue :). Glad to help